# Making cumulative sum with ids and dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum, aggregate-functions

Imagine I have this:

| id | transactiondate | transactiontag | clientid | transactionvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-28 | pizza | 0 | 29.99 |
| 2 | 2020-12-29 | payment | 0 | -39.99 |
| 3 | 2020-12-28 | cheese | 0 | -109.99 |
| 4 | 2020-12-28 | cheese | 0 | -109.99 |
| 5 | 2020-12-28 | pizza | 1 | -19.99 |
| 6 | 2020-12-28 | cheese | 1 | -18.99 |
| 7 | 2020-12-28 | salary | 1 | 58.99 |
| 8 | 2020-12-29 | salary | 1 | 38.99 |

So I have all the Ids of transactions, when they were made by whom and how much they paid, what I needed to do is a cumulative sum for each date and for each individual, so the answer should be this:

this code -> `SELECT distinct accountid, transactiondate, SUM(transactionvalue) OVER(ORDER BY transactiondate) AS cumulative_sum FROM acc_transactions where accountid = 1;` gives me this

| clientid | date | cumulative_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-28 | 20.01 |
| 1 | 2020-12-29 | 59.00 |

the thing is that I need this both for clientid 1 and 0, tried everything I could so far! Need a hero rightnow haha!

Example of right answer ↓

| clientid | date | cumulative_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-28 | 20.01 |
| 1 | 2020-12-29 | 59.00 |
| 0 | 2020-12-28 | -189.99 |
| 0 | 2020-12-29 | -229.98 |

Comment: Maybe because you are adding an extra `where clientid = 1` so your results still stick to the client id 1?

Comment: Is `clientid` = `accountid`? Data and query example have a mismatch.

Comment: Infact query in question and its result mismatches. Result must be 4 records not 2 for acctountid = 1

Comment: @Mostav I added that to show what I had so far, the "logic" of the cumsum was being done but only when pre selected one clientid, i needed the same answer but to be done in all the client ids.

Comment: @tcadidot0 yeah, sorry for that clientid = accountid, too long time looking at it made me mad hahaha!

Comment: @Popeye the result of the query is the one right bellow it and I took it from MySQL workbench, just added the names of the columns :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want a daily aggregation:

```
select accountid, transactiondate, 
    sum(transactionvalue) as transactionvalue
from acc_transactions 
group by accountid, transactiondate
order by accountid, transactiondate
```

Then, you can use window functions on top of it:

```
select accountid, transactiondate, 
    sum(sum(transactionvalue)) 
        over(partition by accountid order by transactiondate) 
        as cumulative_sum
from acc_transactions
group by accountid, transactiondate
order by accountid, transactiondate
```

Comment: I don't think it's that complicated your first part of the answer is enough?

Comment: @Mostav: the question and the data suggest that the OP wants a cumulative sum - that's what the second query does.

Comment: @GMB will try that now but thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: @GMB Perfect! Are you a wizard? hahaha Thank you very much man!